# Order of deletion with foreign key constraints,

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a schema with three tables and foreign key 'On Delete' constraints as below:

```
               |      ->         FK (cascade)        ->       |
Organisation   |                                              |  Users
               | - FK (cascade) Categories -> FK(restrict) -> |
```

If I delete an organisation I want to delete the users and the categories related to it, but I can't allow a category to be deleted if a user refers to it except in the case where the whole organisation is being deleted.

At present if I delete an organisation the category deletion fails if there's a user referring to it. This seems to indicate that MySQl is processing the foreign key constraints on the Categories table before the Users table.

This wouldn't be a problem if the Users in the user table were cleared before the Categories.

**Is there a way to tell MySQl what order to process these FK constraints so that the tables get cleared in a specified order?**

Note: I could add some code to explicitly clear the user table first, but that's fiddly within the design of the code so I don't want to go there yet.

Note also that the required security limits what I can do with the schema on-the-fly, so changing the FK constraints or disabling checking of them is not really an option. I can change the security to make a one-time change. I don't want to loosen security permanently unless there's no other way. Writing extra code as above is preferred

Here are the Create statements for the tables, edited to remove unrelated fields.

```
CREATE TABLE `organisation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orgGUID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `archivedFlag` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `orgName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `org_guid_UNIQUE` (`orgGUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=83 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userGUID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `orgGUID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `userType` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PwHash` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ethnicityGUID` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `genderGUID` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `yearGroupGUID` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userGUID_UNIQUE` (`userGUID`),
  KEY `fk_user_org_idx` (`orgGUID`),
  KEY `fk_ethnicity_category_idx` (`ethnicityGUID`),
  KEY `fk_gender_category_idx` (`genderGUID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ethnicity_category` FOREIGN KEY (`ethnicityGUID`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_gender_category` FOREIGN KEY (`genderGUID`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_org` FOREIGN KEY (`orgGUID`) REFERENCES `organisation` (`orgGUID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=162 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `orgGUID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `categoryType` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `analysisCode` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_category_org_idx` (`orgGUID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_category_org` FOREIGN KEY (`orgGUID`) REFERENCES `organisation` (`orgGUID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I question your foreign key/table design.  Please include table creation statements for all the tables.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Done.

Comment: As I understand: organization -> category -> user; in that case you are unnecessarily duplicating data by putting both category id and organization id in the user table, when category id should have been enough. Secondly, this approach is error prone, because a wrong query operation can change value of organization id, without changing category id; making data corrupt. if you still need organization id in user table, you should implement composite foreign key of (organization id and category id)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I see why you might think that, but the category is more complex than just a hierarchy as you describe. A radical change to the schema might be the right approach, but the user hierarchy originates in an older system onto which the category has been grafted. I don't have time to rewrite all the PHP to rebuild the schema in a meaningful way. For now, I need to be able to delete an organisation and the associated data. If need be I'll extend the PHP that deletes the organisation to delete the subsidiary records first, but if there is a simple MySQL fix that would be preferable.

Comment: @CannonFodder You will need to setup triggers on `before delete` on organization table. This will clean up `user` table before deleting it from the organization table. Now, when organization table gets deleted, cascade will ensure cleanup from the category table. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially, you have no control over the order of the cascaded operations. You may be able to abuse some *undocumented* behaviour however:

- for MySQL 5.5, the foreign keys are executed in the order they got created, so dropping and recreating the `fk_category_org`-constraint should work
- for MySQL 5.6+, the foreign keys are executed in the lexical order of their names, so renaming `fk_category_org` to e.g. `fk_z_category_org` should work

This is undocumented and can change anytime (and might be influenced by other factors).

That being said, the proper way to do this (and anything else too complicated for `on cascade`) would be to add a `before delete`-[trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) on your `organisation`-table that "manually" deletes the users first and then the categories afterwards. `before delete`-triggers are executed before `on cascade` (so you can decide if you want to keep those or not, although it would probably be misleading).

It is not entirely clear if that is your intented behaviour, but currently, a user can have a category that belongs to organization 1 while he is assigned to organization 2. Deleting organization 1 would then still fail. It looks a bit as if that is what you want to prevent by your design, but if you want the deletion to work in this case too, you *need* to use the trigger to be able to incorporate that (or manually delete it in your application), cascading will not work unless you also cascade in the category table.

Comment: Wondering what is the source of *undocumented* behaviour ;) +1

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Well, I guess the best source of undocumented behaviour is usually stackoverflow (and it probably actually is already here somewhere).

Comment: If you come across the link, do share - will be handy. Thanks

Comment: @solarflare the undocumented behaviour is interesting, but I can see it giving rise to an unexpected problem at some time in the future. I hadn't considered triggers in the database, but that amounts to a MySQL approach to what I would otherwise do in PHP. My hesitation is that it becomes some database magic that some hapless developer has to understand at some point in the future. It's not really what I was hoping for, but needs must. +1 for the suggestion :)

Comment: @CannonFodder Yes, since there is proper way, you should probably not use/abuse that behaviour, but since you specifically asked for a way to influence the order, I wanted to let you know. I don't share your scepticism regarding triggers however. They are the prefered method to enforce logic/constraints that the db otherwise doesn't provide, since you do not have to implement that logic in every client (you may e.g. use phpmyadmin?). In your case, the worst thing you can get is an error message, but in many other cases, relying on the client to do all required steps can easily backfire.

Comment: Yes, triggers are the way to do.

Comment: Triggers it is. I'll make sure that the 'magic' is well documented for any subsequent developers to follow.