# Foreign key conflict. Need to prevent delete on middle level - but allow delete when initiated from top parent

Tags: mysql

In the (artificial) example below, I've got a department that has products and for each product there can be one or more "stock" rows (e.g., Inventory).  I've got a foreign key setup that prevents a product from being deleted if there are any child stock rows - and that works fine.  However, I've got a situation where a department row needs to be deleted - and when that happens I want all the child rows (products and stock) to cascade and be deleted. Is it possible to do this in mysql?  I get the sense that it's not possible to have it both ways - protect on a middle level - but delete when initiated from the top parent.

I'm getting the following error when attempting to delete a dept.

Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wbx`.`stock`, CONSTRAINT `fk_stock_product` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dept` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dept_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_product_dept_idx` (`dept_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_dept`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dept_id`)
    REFERENCES `dept` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dept_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `qty` DECIMAL(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_stock_dept_idx` (`dept_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_stock_product_idx` (`product_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_stock_dept`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dept_id`)
    REFERENCES `dept` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_stock_product`
    FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`)
    REFERENCES `product` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `wbx` ;

INSERT INTO `wbx`.`dept` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('1', 'Sales');

INSERT INTO `wbx`.`product` (`id`, `dept_id`, `description`) VALUES ('1', '1', 'Boots');

INSERT INTO `wbx`.`stock` (`id`, `dept_id`, `product_id`, `qty`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '5');

delete from dept where id=1'
```

Comment: Does your product share one-one relationship with dept?

Comment: Please add INSERT statements with sample data and the query which fails.

Comment: Insert statements added.  You can't delete Product #1 which is correct because  there's a stock row associated with it.  But you can't delete Dept #1 either which I need to do.  FYI - the real-life scenario is an app with many customers.  Each customer had many tables underneath it.  But when the customer decides not to use the app anymore I need to delete the customer and all associated data.  If necessary I can start deleting from the bottom until foreign key issues are gone - but it would be nice to just delete the client row and cascade everything down.

Comment: Interesting problem. And I have no clue how to solve it. But the requirement is also a little bit strange. It's like forbidding to saw off a branch because there are leaves on it. But it's fine to fell the whole tree :-)

Comment: Paul - Agreed, it is strange.  This is for an accounting system (like Freshbooks) and I need data integrity for all of a customer's data (e.g., estimates, invoices, payments, etc.) - but when the customer no longer wants to use the app I need to be able to remove all of the customer's data - so at that point I don't care anymore about integrity for the client's data - they're not using the app anymore.

Comment: Just an idea to try, but perhaps drop the foreign keys from the CREATE TABLE statements and manually add them in the order you need them enforced. I.E. Add the cascade to stock, before the cascade to products, and the restrict after everything else. _Of course, even if it works, this kind of solution treads into the "undocumented, non-guaranteed behavior that could break at any time" territory._

Comment: @Uueerdo "manually add them in the order you need them enforced." - I had the same idea - but [failed](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aRDjuvYVpuTy2fUqekotFj/0).

Comment: Yep, whatever MySQL's method for determining which order to cascade such constraints, it must not be by order defined (or name of the constraint... I tried modifying your attempt forcing the restricted one to be last alphabetically with no luck either).

Comment: [Got it](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ddBi7JQwxhBT3pXFscdRNo/0) - "alphabetically" was the correct key word :-)

Comment: @Uueerdo - Your Idea - You write the answer :-) With the disclaimer "undocumented, non-guaranteed behavior".

Comment: Eh, I wouldn't rely on that; your "got it" example should not need the numbers in the fk names if it were purely alphabetical as fk_stock_product should already be enforced after fk_stock_dept if that were the case; but if I take the numbers out it breaks again.

Comment: @Uueerdo if you remove the numbers, former fk2 will be executed first (fk_p < fk_s), violating former fk3, so it still fits. Lexigraphical seems (for MySQL 5.6+) to be the execution order, I came to a similar conclusion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52885132). @BobGlass: the proper solution (that would not rely on undocumented behaviour) would be to use a `before delete`-trigger on `dept` (where you would first delete stocks, then products). Would that be an option?

Comment: @Solarflare Ah, yeah, I see that now; I was completely overlooking the second one.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  I think I'll either go with the before delete trigger per @Uueerdo or just issue 2 delete statements in a transaction (first stock and then dept).

Comment: @BobGlass yeah, Solarflare's before delete trigger suggestion is probably the most reliable way to go, and will prevent you from needing to reproduce the other two deletes with any dept delete statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of deletion with foreign key constraints,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885132/order-of-deletion-with-foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: @Solarflare IMHO we can close this as duplicate. Exactly same problem and same solution.